# Change path of file for logrus level output to file

Tags: go, logging

I'm using [Logrus](https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus) with [lfshook](https://github.com/rifflock/lfshook) to persist log output to file. I'm able to set a specific `path for each output level`.
The problem is that I need to change this path in runtime and I'm unable to do so.

My code working right now:

```
pathMap := MakePath(
   fileLevel,
   absolutePath,
   logPath,
)

log.Hooks.Add(lfshook.NewHook(
   pathMap,
   &logrus.TextFormatter{
      TimestampFormat:        config.Logging.TimestampFormat,
      DisableTimestamp:       !config.Logging.Timestamps,
      DisableLevelTruncation: config.Logging.DisableLevelTruncation,
      FullTimestamp:          true,
      DisableColors:          true,
   },
))

------------------------------------
func MakePath(minLevel logrus.Level, fpath, logPath string) lfshook.PathMap {
    pm := lfshook.PathMap{}

    for _, lvl := range logrus.AllLevels {
        if lvl <= minLevel {
            pm[lvl] = fpath
        }
        pm[logrus.WarnLevel] = logPath + "/logs/teste.log" //Here I create a custom path for WARNING level.
    }

    return pm
}
```

How could I change  the path for a specific level on a `different file`?

Comment: So, you set paths for logging levels at beginning, and later at some time, you want to change path for specific log level, right?

Comment: @GrigoriyMikhalkin Yes sir. Because I will have to make N `files.log` and the information for that name I'll get only later on. That's why I need to change.

Comment: Did you looked at https://github.com/lestrrat-go/file-rotatelogs? It allows you to generate multiple log files with timestamp in their name, like `path+".%Y%m%d%H%M"` -- or it's not what you want?

Comment: I already have that in a different situation. I do need to specify a name manually... The name of the file must match the name of the device that will connect to my application later on...

Comment: In that case, you can initialize different logger for each device or write your own [io.Writer](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer) for which you will be able to change output manually.

Comment: @GrigoriyMikhalkin I see. Thanks! Could you provide a snippet? I'm really new to Golang and not sure how to do that exactly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210620/discussion-between-grigoriy-mikhalkin-and-playhardgopro).